# PHP Server Socket shutting down at seemingly random instances

Tags: php, sockets

I have a server online, and I wrote a PHP Code to act as a Socket Server to handle messages. The messages are coming in from devices that connect to the IP and the Port and send messages.

I found [this code example](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php#109888) that lets me handle multiple connections at the same time and manage the messages as they come in.

I have modified the code to properly parse the messages that come in from my devices.

Everything has been going well during testing. However, when we did extended testing, the PHP Socket Server would shutdown at seemingly random times and would give the error:

```
socket_read() failed: reason: Connection reset by Peer at line 104.
```

Looking at the code I am running, this is the code block for line 104, it starts at the if condition.

```
if (false === ($buf = socket_read($client, 115200, PHP_BINARY_READ))) {
    echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($client)) . "\n";
    $GLOBALS['mysqli']->close();
    break 2;
}
```

I actually am not sure how to make sense of this error message. During our testing periods, sometimes that error would show up and shut down the Socket Server while the device is sending a message - but we are sure that the device did not send a Socket Shutdown command. At other times, when we would let the Socket Server just run through, that error would show up.

Does anyone know how to effectively keep a PHP Socket Server from shutting down and keep on running?

I know I can run a cronjob that periodically checks if the socket is being used. However, when the socket server shuts down unexpectedly, the PHP Code can't execute as it still reads that the port is still in use, even if the previous socket server instance is already down and we can no longer connect to it. It takes quite some time until the cronjob manages to put the socket back up again and accept messages - and we need the socket server to run virtually all the time.

Comment: What is `break 2;`?

Comment: @EdHeal I actually am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection reset by Peer" means the client disconnected unexpectedly. For instance, the user may have closed the client before it was done talking to the server.

Your server code needs to be prepared to handle errors on client sockets, and not quit when it gets an error on a client socket. When you get an error from a client socket it's appropriate to just disconnect that client.